# Check whether multiplication will overflow

Tags: c++, math, overflow, numeric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Currently I use the following function:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
bool is_mul_safe(T x, U y) {
    return (ld(x * 1.) + ld(y * 1.)) - (sizeof(decltype(x * y)) << 3) <= 0;
}
```

Is there a standard library function which provides the same functionality?

Comment: Btw. I would like to know if there's any type_trait I could replace the decltype with.

Comment: I'd simply perform the multiplication and use a subsequent division to check if there was an overflow.  Thtis will be certainly faster than calling `ld()` twice.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what's `ld`? Is that standard C?

Comment: Are T and U unsigned integer types?

Comment: ld (logarithm dualis) is basically a `static inline` helper function which returns `::log(x) / ::log(2)`. Just for convenience. T and U should be numeric types.

Comment: "numeric types"? That includes floating-point types! How on earth is your `sizeof(decltype)` going to work for floating-point types? Get a grip, FrEEzE2046.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I mean is "integral types". However, this could be done ensured with enable_if.